# Convert between int array or tuple vs bytes correctly

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, integer, tuples

Hi I have these codes to convert between int arrays and bytes type variables:

```
def BYTES_INTARRAY(x):
    data_ints = struct.unpack('<' + 'B'*len(x), x)
    return data_ints

def INTARRAY_BYTES(x):
    data_bytes = struct.pack('<' + 'B'*len(x), *x)
    return data_bytes
```

It seems to work well for bytes that are longer than 1 but when there is only 1 byte it gives a weird result.

For example:

```
print(        INTARRAY_BYTES([255,25])              )
```

Returns: `b'\xff\x19'`

Then fed back:

```
print(        BYTES_INTARRAY(b'\xff\x19')              )
```

Returns:
`(255, 25)`

But if there is only 1 byte:

```
print(        INTARRAY_BYTES([255])              )
```

Returns: `b'\xff'`

And fed back:

```
print(        BYTES_INTARRAY(b'\xff')              )
```

Returns: `(255,)`

## Questions:

1) What the hell is that `,` after the 255. I don't understand the syntax of putting and empty comma there after a number.

2) This code was for python 2.x, is there are more efficient way to do this for python 3.x?

Comment: The single comma is the syntax for a tuple with a single element.  `(1+2)` would be `3`, an integer, while `(1+2,)` would be `(3,)`, a tuple. You don't want to have to guess if your program is going to return a tuple of integers or a single integer, so it always returns a tuple, even if it just has one item.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I see, thanks, I am newbie when it comes to tuples. Do you think there is a more python 3.x way of doing this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) can be created directly from iterables of integers:

```
bytes([255, 25])
# b'\xff\x19'
```

and iterating over `bytes` yields integers

```
tuple(b'\xff\x19')
# (255, 25)
```